Creating a Dynamic Panel in WordPress
I want to create a dynamic panel for my WordPress theme using PHP code. To do this, I have placed the following code in the functions.php file:
function dynamic_panel($title, $content) {
  $allowed_tags = '<p><strong><em><img>'; // List of allowed tags
  $content = wp_kses($content, $allowed_tags); // Sanitize content with allowed tags

  // Extract image content from $content
  $image_pattern = '/<img[^>]*?>/i'; // Regex pattern to match image tags
  preg_match($image_pattern, $content, $image_matches);

  if (isset($image_matches[0])) {
    $image_html = $image_matches[0]; // Extract the first image tag
    $text_content = preg_replace($image_pattern, '', $content); // Remove image tag from text content
  } else {
    $image_html = ''; // No image found
    $text_content = $content; // Text content remains unchanged
  }

  echo '<div id="panelMine"';
  echo '<div>';
  echo '<ul>';
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<p class="fas fa-circle-chevron-right">&shy;</p>';
  echo '<p class="fas fa-circle-chevron-down">&shy;</p>';
  echo '<h3>' . $title . '</h3>';
  echo '<ul>';
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<hr>';

  // Display image if available
  if ($image_html) {
    echo $image_html;
  }

  echo '<p>' . $text_content . '</p>'; // Display text content

  echo '<hr>';
  echo '</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}

function dynamic_panel_shortcode($atts) {
  $title = isset($atts['title']) ? $atts['title'] : '';
  $content = isset($atts['content']) ? $atts['content'] : '';

  return dynamic_panel($title, $content);
}

add_shortcode('dynamic_panel', 'dynamic_panel_shortcode');

With the code above, I can now easily create a panel on the page in the WordPress post editor using the following shortcode:
[dynamic_panel title="Title Contect" content="content"]

So far, everything works fine without any problems. However, if I use the shortcode as follows:
[dynamic_panel title="Title Contect" content="
<img src="http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/WordPress-background_15-300x188.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="188" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-132" />
"]

Naturally, it should display a panel with an image as its content. But this is not happening!
When I check the HTML of the page, I see only an empty <p> tag in the panel content between the <li> tags, and there is no <img> tag!
I would be very grateful for any help in solving this problem.

I have had a good comb of the internet and I can't find one example of the $allowed_html parameter of wp_kses() being passed in as a string -- it is always an associative array.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/  Have you tried defining your whitelist of tags as an array instead of a string?

I would recommend using the longer-form of shortcodes which has a closing tag, this allows you to put HTML or other things inside of it.
[dynamic_panel title="Title"]
    <img src="/site/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/WordPress-background_15-300x188.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="188" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-132" />
[/dynamic_panel]

The contents, if provided, will then be passed to the second parameter of the function, so you can update your code with:
function dynamic_panel_shortcode($atts, $content) {
  $title = $atts['title'] ?? '';
  if(!$content){
    $content = $atts['content'] ?? '';
  }

  return dynamic_panel($title, $content);
}

add_shortcode('dynamic_panel', 'dynamic_panel_shortcode');


Hi.Thank you very much for your help. In the section: $title = $atts['title']) ?? '';, you had added one**)** and the code was executed by removing it. But still I only get a single <p> and no <img> tag?

Okay, that has been fixed, thanks. For your next problem we need to see if this is a shortcode issue or a wp_kses issue. Inside of dynamic_panel_shortcode, right before the return, add var_dump($content) to see what's in there. If you don't see an img tag, the problem is with the shortcode. If you do see an img tag, then the problem is later on. I'm guessing it is the latter.

By adding var_dump($content) to my main code, I see something like this in the output before the panel: string(6) " "

With a bit of space before the code $content = wp_kses($content, $allowed_tags); Now I can see the image well.

In the output now: string(175) " <img src="/site/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/WordPress-background_15-300x188.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="188" class ="alignnone size-medium wp-image-132" /> " is visible.

I found the problem! By removing the code $content = wp_kses($content, $allowed_tags);  I can easily see the content of the image. Won't this cause disruption in the future?
